# How a shortcut object is linked with a Crystal Report object in CI_INFOOBJECTS

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

I'm working with the Business Objects JAVA SDK and I need a QUERY to retrieve shortcut linked to a specific instance of a Crystal Report.

I'm able to retrieve shortcut object or crystal Report instance but I can't find the field mapping both of them together.

Here's the query retrieving the Crystal Report Instance :

```
private static String QUERY_REPORT_BY_ID="SELECT * " + 
"FROM   CI_INFOOBJECTS " + 
"WHERE  SI_KIND = 'CrystalReport' AND SI_INSTANCE_OBJECT=1 AND SI_ID = 'REPLACE_REPORT_ID' "  + 
"ORDER BY SI_NAME";
```

From this I have the IInfoObject, can I delete the shortcut of the object?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve the shortcut as an `IInfoObject`.  So:

```
select *
  from ci_infoobjects
 where si_alias_targetid = 1234
```

Replace 1234 with the ID of the CR instance.  This query will retrieve any and all shortcuts that point to it.